# Non-English Wordcloud in python 3

Tags: python, fonts, word-cloud

I am trying to create wordcloud in python 3 with wordcloud package library. 
The problem is that I get the rectangular images instead of words because I want to do it on Georgian words, not English.
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I wonder if something can be done with indicating Georgian fonts.

Thank you.

Comment: You should add your code to the post.